# How to teleport a player into the air using "~ ~ ~"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking to teleport a person using a command like

```
/tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

I would like to teleport a player one block into the air.

Is this the command? If not, what is it? How do I use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will teleport a player one block into the air:

```
/tp @p ~0 ~1 ~0
```

Here is the breakdown:

- `/tp` - The command to teleport a player
- `@p` - The player closest to you. Also, if you are playing with [Command Blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block), then this will teleport the player standing closest to the command block.

The next three are the X, Y, and Z coordinates. The tilde means "relative to the current position".

- `~0` - Zero blocks in the X (East/West) direction
- `~1` - Positive one blocks in the Y (Up/Down) direction
- `~0` - Zero blocks in the Z (North/South) direction

A tilde by itself is shorthand for `~0`. For example, the following will teleport the player down (in the negative Y direction) five blocks.

```
/tp @p ~ ~-5 ~
```

Comment: `@p` isn't just for command blocks; it's the closest player to whatever is running the command (doesn't have to be standing on it).

Comment: What would be the command to teleport the player 5 block down?

Comment: @colorfusion I had no idea, so thanks! Will update the answer.

Comment: @Jake I modified the second example to kill two birds with one stone. It now shows how to move a player down.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the current info with that in the first comment.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson Thanks for doing that! I approved the edit shortly afterwards.